# Split the use of "n_jobs" in sklearn between StackingClassifier and estimators

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

Say I have the following flow

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


X,y = get_data()

logreg = LogisticRegression(n_jobs = -1)
svm_pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),LinearSVC())
estimators = [("logreg",logreg),("svm",svm_pipeline)

k = 5

stacker = StackingClassifier(n_jobs=-1,cv=k)
stacker.fit(X,y)
```

This throws some warnings since `StackingClassifier` and `LogisticRegression` both have `n_jobs=-1`, which makes sense.

I assume that since `k=5` (number of folds) and `len(estimators)=2` `StackingClassifier` uses (atleast) 5x2=10 cores if `n_jobs=-1`. Since I have 64 cores that would leave 54 cores unsused, which `LogisticRegression` could benefit greatly from.

So, with that logic, could I then set `n_jobs = 54//k` in `logreg` (since we would have `k` instances of `logreg` which should split the remaining 54 cores) and `n_jobs = 10` for `StackingClassifier`, or how would I optimize the core usage? I'm not entirely sure how sklearn manages multiprocessing when `n_jobs=-1`, or how it optimizes `StackingClassifiers` with multiprocessing (apart from my guess above).